# How to make shaking animation on android like iOS has?

Tags: android

Does anybody has an example of animation that looks like tilting slightly on left and right but middle is not moving. It looks like when you want to move icons on iOS and make a long press you could see that kind of animation what I need. I got animation but it more looks like moving the whole item instead of tilting. Here is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="70"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="40%"
        android:pivotY="40%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toDegrees="1" />
    <translate
        android:duration="70"
        android:fromXDelta="-3"
        android:fromYDelta="3"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toXDelta="0.1" />
</set>
```

Its like wiggling effect on this screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The rotation effect can be made by adding 2 parameters

```
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="3"
```

Comment: is this the answer or a comment?

Comment: do you have any other solutions @AymenBenSalah